# Facebook app bundle identifier

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I have Facebook share in my iOS application,i have created a Facebook app in Facebook developer account with my bundle id.Later i have changed my bundle identifier in my application,but not changed in Facebook app.Currently its working fine,whether any problem arises due to this.Is it necessary to change bundle identifier in facbook app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you must have to change bundle ID at Facebook too. Currently it is running because may be your **login session is not expired yet**. Try to delete your current app from simulator or device and run again. When facebook try to login it will give you error.

Also, you could define multiple bundle ID on Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

Every Facebook APP ID is associated with a particular bundle id. I also encountered with this situtation in the past as bundle id was not changed in Facebook app it worked for a while but after sometime it shows me **invalid sso_key parameter** error. So I think you might need to change the bundle id in the Facebook app as well.
[image: Attached is the error screen while authentication]